# Nested foreach loops

Tags: php

I know this solution is simple, but it keeps slipping my mind. When I parse the page with this code and the `$links` array is printed, all of `href` parts are correct yet the `img` part only prints the last `src` element that is found on the page.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$links = array();
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");
$arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach($arr as $item) {
        // get links
        $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");

        // get images.
        foreach ($images as $item) {
            $img = $item->getAttribute('src');
        }    

        $links[] = array(
            'href' => $href,
            'img' => $img
        );
    }

print_r(array_values($links));
```

Comment: that's because `$img` gets replaced with a new value with each iteration yet you only put `$img` into the new array *after* the loop is done.

Comment: put like this second foreach $img[] and use $img,i think it works

Comment: What is this code trying to accomplish?  It seems strange to have nested `foreach` loops in this situation.

Comment: This code is just supposed to parse an html page and return the href and img source into an array.

Answer (score 0):

The for each statement for images should be building an array where as the final array ($links)is a multi-dimentional array($img being the nested array).

Answer (score 0):

You use the dublicate variable `$item` in internal foreach.

Try this without internal foreach

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$links = array();
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");
$arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach($arr as $key=>$item) {
        // get links
        $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");

        $img = $images[$key]->getAttribute('src');

        $links[] = array(
            'href' => $href,
            'img' => $img
        );
    }unset($item);

print_r(array_values($links));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$links = array();
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");
$arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($arr as $item) {
    // get links
    $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");

    // get images.
    foreach ($images as $item) {
        $img = $item->getAttribute('src');

        // storing the image src 
        $links[] = array(
           'img' => $img
        );
    }    

    $links[] = array(
        'href' => $href
    );
}

print_r(array_values($links));
```